# Cannot interact with JavaScript API of model-viewer component after updating a state in a React function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, model-viewer

I am using the `model-viewer` component from `@google/model-viewer` in my React function component.

This is my code:

```
export default function RobotDetails() {
    const [url, setUrl] = useState("../models/forks.glb");
    const defaultCameraOrbit = "45deg 55deg 5m";
    var mv = document.querySelector("model-viewer");


    function changeModel(modelName: string) {
        setUrl(`../models/${modelName}.glb`);
        setCameraOrbit();
    }

    function setCameraOrbit(orbit: string = defaultCameraOrbit) {
        mv!.cameraOrbit = orbit;
    }

    return (
        ...
            <div className="modelview-container">
                <model-viewer src={new URL(url, import.meta.url).href} camera-orbit="45deg 55deg 4m" camera-controls touch-action="none" interaction-prompt="none" />

                <div className="model-select-left">
                    <button onClick={() => changeModel("table")}>Arm</button>
                </div>
                <div className="model-select-right">
                    <button onClick={() => changeModel("forks")}>Forks</button>
                    <button onClick={() => setCameraOrbit()}>Reset</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        ...
    );
}
```

However I am having an issue with the `useState` hook. I believe it may stems from this line in the react docs:

> The set function only updates the state variable for the next render. If you read the state variable after calling the set function, you will still get the old value that was on the screen before your call.

`setCameraOrbit` is a user-defined function that accesses the JavaScript API of the `model-viewer`element in order to reset its camera orbit to a previously defined value, or a new value if specified.

`setCameraOrbit` works fine when run on its own (e.g. the "Reset" button defined in the HTML), but when called by `changeModel` it only works if the url doesn't change. Meaning that it only works if the `url` state isn't new, causing `setUrl` to not trigger a reactive update cycle.

For example, if the state of `url` is currently set to `"../models/forks.glb"`, and I click the "Forks" button, then `setUrl` notices that the current state and new state are the same, and so does not trigger a re-render. In this case, the `setCameraOrbit` call in `changeModel` works as intended. However, if I instead click the "Arm" button, the current state of `url` (`"../models/forks.glb"`) does not match the new state (`"../models/table.glb"`), which causes `setUrl` to trigger a re-render. In this case, the `setCameraOrbit` in `changeModel` does not work as intended. While it still runs, the camera does not visually update.

I also get this warning in the devtools console:

```
Element model-viewer scheduled an update (generally because a property was set) after an update completed, causing a new update to be scheduled. This is inefficient and should be avoided unless the next update can only be scheduled as a side effect of the previous update. See https://lit.dev/msg/change-in-update for more information.
```

I have looked into trying to force react to re-render before calling `setCameraOrbit`, however there doesn't really seem to be a good way to do this in a functional react component.

What are some possible ways to make the `setCameraOrbit` function work right after `setUrl` is called?

Alternatively, what are some ways to run `setCameraOrbit` whenever the `src` attribute of the `model-viewer` component updates?

Comment: What exactly is `setCameraOrbit` supposed to do? What does the `url` state have to do with anything `setCameraOrbit` does? This doesn't appear to be a question about React hooks, or any issue with them, but rather what happens *after* the state update is enqueued and `setCameraOrbit` isn't working as you expect. Please [edit] to clarify what exactly the issue or problem is with the model code/logic.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I updated the question to hopefully be more clear on what the issue is. I used the react-hooks tag on the question because my issue seemed to be caused by `useState`, and many of the potential solutions that I was aware of involved react hooks, which I wasn't clear on the best way to use. While it isn't technically the hook itself causing the issue, it is the state change triggered by the hook, so I had thought it was appropriate.

Comment: I don't think the state update has anything to do with this really, not directly at least. It seems that whatever new `src` attribute is used/passed is the issue, that the `model-viewer` element doesn't update. Try adding a React key to `model-viewer`, e.g. `key={url}`.

Comment: Sorry if this wasn't clear, the issue is not with the model changing itself. The issue is only with the `setCameraOrbit` function, which doesn't reset the camera orbit when it is called in `changeModel`. Other than that specific functionality, `changeModel` and `setCameraOrbit` work fine.